Solving a TSP using QAOA
I am reading the QAOA applications and trying the tutorial https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm. I want to just share what I have learnt about QAOA. We have a (say) optimization problem. We have to convert that Problem into a QUBO. We find the cost Hamiltonian of that objective function. Next step is to construct a mixer Hamiltonian. The parameters of that operator are what we are looking for. Once we set up this parametrized circuit. We send it to the estimator which takes as argument, the parametrized circuit. The estimator runs this circuit for a several times, and then calculates the expected value of the cost Hamiltonian. Now these expected values are sent to the classical optimizer with the parameters. The classical optimizer iterates and find the optimal (near optimal) parameters. Finally, the optimized circuit is run a final time on the sampler, which samples the bit strings. The optimum bit string should be seen with high probability.
Now I have a few questions. The tutorial does not make the mixer hamiltonian? Does the QAOA ansatz by default makes the mixer  with this command
 circuit = QAOAAnsatz(cost_operator=cost_hamiltonian, reps=2)

When I run the exact same code with the TSP Hamiltonian
  n = 3
  num_qubits = n**2
  tsp = Tsp.create_random_instance(n, seed=123)
  adj_matrix = nx.to_numpy_array(tsp.graph)
  qp = tsp.to_quadratic_program()
  from qiskit_optimization.converters import QuadraticProgramToQubo
  qp2qubo = QuadraticProgramToQubo()
  qubo = qp2qubo.convert(qp)
  cost_hamiltonian, offset = qubo.to_ising()

So I have my cost Hamiltonian for my TSP on 2 cities only.
The optimizer ran with the parameters
         result = minimize(
         cost_func_estimator,
         init_params,
         args=(candidate_circuit, cost_hamiltonian, estimator),
         method="COBYLA",
         tol=1e-12,
)
  The optimizer ran and stopped with the outcome  

           message: Optimization terminated successfully.
           success: True
           status: 1
           fun: 20.84815184815175
           x: [ 4.142e+00  1.570e+00  3.146e+00  1.568e+00  3.137e+00
            1.568e+00]
           nfev: 150
           maxcv: 0.0

I ran the code for the final time on the sampler as given in the above tutorial, however the results that I am getting, are everytime changing and not even once giving the right answer. I mean what is wrong with this approach.  Is this something to do with my approach or the QAOA has this limitation. So what class of problems will the QAOA solve efficiently.
How do interpret the results from the QAOA into classical. I am genuinely in need of help.

You have the optimal parameters. That is what this line is
x: [ 4.142e+00  1.570e+00  3.146e+00  1.568e+00  3.137e+00 1.568e+00]
Now run the circuit on the sampler with those parameters to get a bitstring.
The bitstring has the information you need, the path information.
You can interpret the bit string for a n = 3 graph like this:
n = 3, so bitstring will be 3^2-3 in length. Break the string into n even components.
So we start with xxxxxx and look at it as xx yy zz.
The first substring, xx, represents all the edges connected to the first node. The characters in the substring represent the connecting node.
For example, xx is node 0 to either 1 or 2, yy is node 1 to either 0 or 2, and
zz is node 2 to either 0 or 1.
We can then use this logic to interpret a string such as 011001.
This represents the path Node 0 -> Node 2 -> Node 1 (and back to zero, but that part isnt in the string)
